# Why does my LED light flicker for a few minutes after being turned on

Tags: electrical, led

I have an LED panel in my bathroom which plugs into a small box labeled *LED driver: input 85-265VAC, output 75-120VDC* which is wired directly to the mains.

When I switch the light on, if it's been off for a long while it will flicker rapidly for a few minutes until eventually it goes on properly.

This light does not have a dimmer switch (I read that that can be the cause of issues like this). I'm not sure if the problem would be fixed by replacing the LED driver, or if I'd have to replace the actual light panel, or if the problem is in the wiring of the house.

Does anyone know what the problem might be, and if possible, how I can fix it?

Edit: I just noticed the LED driver makes a constant pretty quiet chirping sound, kind of like a quiet cricket

Comment: Why is "output voltage" a range instead of a number?  There is an answer and it's very important to selecting the correct driver.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That's what it's labelled as... Do you think the problem is that it's outputting the wrong voltage? Or are you trying to say that my new driver would have to match the actual voltage which is unlabelled?

Comment: Is there a label on the LED panel saying what it needs for voltage/amps/watts or what driver it needs?

Comment: @crip659 i believe it said 65 Watts. it said nothing about volts or amps

Comment: I'm trying to prod you to learn more about how LED drivers work.

Comment: Will it fit in an answer ;)

Comment: measure the voltage fed to the LEDs at the start and after 10 mins; is it out of bounds?

Comment: "75-120VDC" seems like a _lot_ of current for DC, especially for LED lighting. Usually, they're called "low voltage" lights because they run on 12 or 24VDC

Comment: @FreeMan "LED lighting" doesn't imply "low voltage". A single LED needs roughly 3V,and a panel can easily comprise tens of LEDs wired in series,which simplifies the driver a lot. Say,the LED backlight in a typical TV is a series string of 50+ LEDs driven at like 150-200V. "LED filament" light bulbs also contain a string of as many LEDs necessary to work directly off mains voltage (like 40 in the US, 80 in Europe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what you have is a "constant current" type LED driver, and it is of the low cost "linear power supply" variety, very common in the type of fixture you describe. One of their down sides is lower efficiency, meaning they create heat and in a "trapped" air flow situation like a bathroom, may suffer from decreased life expectancy, leading to flickering as it slowly dies.

TL;DR
It was a cheap fixture to start with and is nearing the end of its life, time to replace it. the LEDs themselves are probably fine, if you find a driver with the same specs, you can just replace that.